# how do i find the location where the unhandled exception happened in msvs 2015

Tags: winforms, exception, visual-studio-2015

solved: the problem was that i was running in solution mode, not in debug mode

since i could not find this answer in search machines, it should be trivial, but i spent and hour and still cannot solve it.

in visual studio 2015 community, winforms application, on debugging the application stops and a window pops up

> Argument exception was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Der Eingabearray ist länger als die Anzahl der Spalten in dieser Tabelle.
> (translation: array is longer than number of columns in this table)

the break mode tab says

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show, because all threads where executing external code (typically system of framework code).

how can i find which table causes the exception? or even better, which line in the code? it's probably while filling a table (i actually know which one in this case). i recently switched to MSVS 2015 and it was no problem in older versions (i think they jumped to the line in the code automatically).

Comment: Just try to reset your debugging exceptions settings: DEBUG->Exceptions->Reset All, and also TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General->Just My Code=True

Comment: Can you look at the stacktrace and follow it back to your code?

Comment: i cannot find debug->exceptions (neighter in the debug menu nor in the options). but i never changed the debugging settings, and when compiling it tells me '1. Use a debug build configuration or disable the debug option 'Enable Just My Code'.' - what is stacktrace? Call Stack just says [external code]